# Как сделать выпадающий список элементы которого можно будет выбрать чекбоксами?

Tags: html, css

Сначала пробовал сделать как-то так:

```
<select id="reward" name="countires" className="input-color">
  <option value="">бла</option>
  <option><input text="checkbox">бла</option>
</select>
```

но вместо чекбокса отображается Object object.

Comment: `<input>` закрывать не нужно, это одиночный тег. https://coderoad.ru/17714705/Как-использовать-Checkbox-внутри-опции-Select#27547021